# Append script tags in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm trying to append this in JS:

```
<script language='javascript'>document.pathXml='xml/infos.xml'</script>
```

this works: (except for the text within the "script" tag);

```
var script   = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "javascript";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

I just tried to do this to add the text :

```
var script   = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "javascript";
$(this).html("document.pathXml='xml/infos.xml'");
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

but it's not working.
Any help is welcome!thanks in advance

Comment: This would work: `script.innerHTML = "document.pathXml='xml/infos.xml'";`

Comment: Or `script.text = "document.pathXml='xml/infos.xml'"`

Comment: `$(this)` should be `$(script)`.

Comment: Window.eval(your script). Executes your string as a script